# Shopping Cart functionality, current_cart method definition on Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, shopping-cart

i´m brand new to Stackoverflow and fairly new to web development in general.
I´ve been learning Rails for a few months and started to build a simple app to teach myself.

I’ll try to be concise and to the point, the app goes like this:  The user signs up or logs in so he can perform CRUD operations to his own Products and Customers. He can also search for customers by phone number, retrieving either the found customer  or a  form to create a new one. Pretty simple. Now, each customer can place many orders (or carts, whatever you want to call it), which store many products, purchased at a given time by a given customer.
You can see a working example here, http://order-checker.herokuapp.com with mocked up cart functionality to see how it should all fit together. 
User: guest, password: abcd1234

Now I’ve wrote a second example with what I have so far in terms of cart functionality, line items models, controllers, etc  and without the user auth for simplicity. https://github.com/gatosaurio/mockup
. Here are my models for this second example:

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :street
  has_many :carts
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :price
end

class Cart < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer
  has_many :line_items
  attr_accessible :purchased_at

  def total_price
    line_items.to_a.sum(&:full_price)
  end
end

class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :cart_id, :product_id, :quantity, :unit_price
  belongs_to :cart
  belongs_to :product

  def full_price
    unit_price * quantity
  end
end
```

So, in the customers index action I have a new_cart_path link for each one of these. In carts#new I want a list of all the products , with an “add to order” post link.

```
  <% @products.each do |product| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= link_to product.name, product_path(product) %></td>
    <td><%= form_tag(line_items_path, :method => "post") do %>
        <%= hidden_field_tag(:product_id, product.id) %>
        <%= submit_tag("Add to Cart") %></td>
   <% end %>


  </tr>
<% end %>
```

The sidebar of this new cart action should also display all the line items associated with this cart, something like this, maybe.

```
<% @cart.line_items.each do |line_item| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= line_item.product.name %></td>
    <td class="qty"><%= line_item.quantity %></td>
    <td class="price"><%= number_to_currency(line_item.unit_price) %></td>
    <td class="price"><%= number_to_currency(line_item.full_price) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to "Delete", line_item, method: :delete, :limit => 1,  data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?'}%></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
<tr>
  <td class="total price" colspan="4">
  <Total: <%= number_to_currency @cart.total_price %></td>
</tr>
```

Now, here´s line_items#create

```
def create
  @product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
  if LineItem.exists?(:cart_id => current_cart.id, :product_id => @product.id)
    item = LineItem.find(:first, :conditions => [ "cart_id = #{current_cart.id} AND product_id = #{@product.id}" ])
        LineItem.update(item.id, :quantity => item.quantity + 1)
  else  
        @line_item = LineItem.create!(:cart => current_cart, :product => @product, :quantity => 1, :unit_price => @product.price)
        flash[:notice] = "Added #{@product.name} to cart."
  end
redirect_to new_cart_path
end
```

So you see, **my specific question** after all this is: **how would I define the current_cart method in application_controller.rb**? And I ask this because all the resources on shopping cart functionality i´ve been able to find from google searching (*Agile Web Development with Rails, 4th Edition*) were almost exclusively dealing with creating a session object for the cart instance, but I find this approach unfitting for my case, since I need each cart associated only with one specific customer instead of a session being held on the app user´s  level.

I really hope this to be a valid question, sory if this is too long and my current rep level doesn't allow me to post more than two link, but you can find all the code on my Github account.

Thanks a lot  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  # Shopping cart, id is in session (if any)
  def current_cart
    Cart.find(session[:cart_id])
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    cart = Cart.create
    session[:cart_id] = cart.id
    cart
  end
```

The cart id is held in the session. If no cart is referenced or found, a new one is created and the id stored in the session. Either way, a cart object is returned.

You will eventually have a lot of empty or stale carts. Remember to set up a clean up job.

Addendum

Your mass assignment error is a result of this line:

```
        @line_item = LineItem.create!(:cart => current_cart, :product => @product, :quantity => 1, :unit_price => @product.price)
```

Here, you create a new `LineItem` by mass assignment. In your model, you allow mass assignment for

```
  attr_accessible :cart_id, :product_id, :quantity, :unit_price
```

and here's the tricky part: though Rails assigns ids internally, it takes your configuration literally. To mass assign to `cart` you need `attr_accessible :cart`. So you can either

```
        @line_item = LineItem.create!(:cart_id => current_cart.id, :product_id => @product.id, :quantity => 1, :unit_price => @product.price)
```

or

```
  attr_accessible :cart, :cart_id, :product, :product_id, :quantity, :unit_price
```

both will work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :)

I did that a few days ago, and I guess I should build a filter to empty the cart session just after I created a new cart object. 

Problem is I'm getting the following error:

Can't mass-assign protected attributes: cart, product

My models are showed in my original question. What i'm I doing wrong here?

Comment: added mass assignment solution to answer

Comment: Thanks a ton! It works now! :)
I'm able to see my line items listed as I wanted. I rewrote it a little, like so:

    def current_cart 
      session[:cart_id] ||= Cart.create!.id
      @current_cart ||= Cart.find(session[:cart_id]) 
    end 

Now i'm working on associating each cart to a specific customer, which i think i'll try to do using nested attributes.

Now i guess i should also build an after_filter into CartsController so each cart session is set to nil after creating a cart instance.

I'll let you know how it went.

Danke schön, hab' doch viel gelernt  :)